# How to use a 1D-CNN model in Lime?

Tags: python, keras, lime

I have a numeric health record dataset. I used a 1D CNN keras model for the classification step.

I am giving a reproductible example in Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Activation, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,2,9,3], [0,5,1,33,6], [1, 12,1,8,9]])
train = np.reshape(a[:,1:],(a[:,1:].shape[0], a[:,1:].shape[1],1))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(a[:,:1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=(train.shape[1], 1), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                 optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False),
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train, y_train, epochs=3, verbose=1)
```

I am getting this error when I apply lime to my 1D CNN model

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

```
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular

explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(train)
```

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I did some minor changes to your initial code (changed from `keras` to `tensorflow.keras`)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, Activation, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,2,9,3], [0,5,1,33,6], [1, 12,1,8,9]])
train = np.reshape(a[:,1:],(a[:,1:].shape[0], a[:,1:].shape[1],1))
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(a[:,:1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', 
     padding="same", input_shape=(train.shape[1], 1), 
kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
             optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, 
             beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False),
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train, y_train, epochs=3, verbose=1)
```

Then I added some test data because you don't want to train and test your LIME model on the same data

```
b = np.array([[1,4,5,3,2], [1,4,2,55,1], [7, 3,22,3,10]])
test = np.reshape(b[:,1:],(b[:,1:].shape[0], b[:,1:].shape[1],1))
```

Here I show how the `RecurrentTabularExplainer` can be trained

```
import lime
from lime import lime_tabular

explainer = lime_tabular.RecurrentTabularExplainer(train,training_labels=y_train, feature_names=["random clf"],
                                               discretize_continuous=False, feature_selection='auto', class_names=['class 1','class 2'])
```

Then you can run your LIME model on one of the examples in your test data:

```
exp = explainer.explain_instance(np.expand_dims(test[0],axis=0), model.predict, num_features=10)
```

and finally display the predictions

```
exp.show_in_notebook()
```

[image: explanations from LIME]

or just printing the prediction

```
print(exp.as_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try **lime_tabular.RecurrentTabularExplainer** instead of LimeTabularExplainer. It is an explainer for keras-style recurrent neural networks. Check out the examples in LIME documentation for better understanding. Good luck:)

Comment: It didn't work                                                                            lime.lime_tabular.RecurrentTabularExplainer(train, feature_names=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lime/lime_tabular.py", line 624, in __init__
    for n in feature_names for i in range(n_timesteps)]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: _TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable_ appears to be a python error. Do check what is causing it

Comment: I can't figure out the problem

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable - means the object causing this error has value 'none' , which means that object does not contain any value. Check which object is causing it in your code.

Comment: This is why I gave a reproductioble example because I'm still having the same error.  lime.lime_tabular.RecurrentTabularExplainer(train, training_labels=y_train , feature_names=None)
  File "lime/lime_tabular.py", line 624, in __init__
    for n in feature_names for i in range(n_timesteps)]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @Noura Did you find what was the problem?